# Animation: Creating random pulses (not noise) on a F-Curve

Tags: modifiers

with a noise modifier on a F-curve I can "shake" something randomly and continuously.

But I need a couple of single "pulses" randomly spread over a sequence of frames with a random amplitude.

How can I do this, when I don't want to animate any single pulse manually?

Answer (score 4):

You can add some different noise modifiers, and restrict their frame range. 
[image]

Comment: Apologies if this is getting you up to your neck.. I'm interested in this, too.. How do you keyframe the influence? Could you drive the influence with noise /  thresholded noise, too, to generate random intervals between pulses automatically?

Comment: I'm sorry, it looks like you cannot animate the influence slider. I thought it was animatable like almost everything in Blender, but I was wrong.

Comment: I thought so, too...

Comment: Sorry ... but this is not, what I wanted. These are "blocks of noises", which kinda blend in and blend out. In betweem them is "stretched noise" and no silent (aka "flat line") at all. What I want is a "flat line.....1 pulse.....flat line" with a "..." of random length and a pulse amplitude of random height and a pulse width of random length. Sounds pedantic...but for the visualization in physical context you cannot state that something "moves a little bit in between"... :) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script to automate the insertion of keyframes.. that may be too inflexible..

Instead, maybe this approach could be a start, using a Driver expression? This generates a noise-based square-wave pulse.. of `amplitude` from 0.

```
import  bpy
from mathutils import noise 


def pulse(frame, speed, uptime, amplitude=1):

    vector_noise = noise.noise_vector((frame*speed,0,0)) 
    uptime_noise = vector_noise[0] + 0.5
    up = (uptime_noise > (1-uptime))
    return up * amplitude


bpy.app.driver_namespace['pulse'] = pulse
```

parameters:

- `frame`: the current frame
- `speed`: scales the noise (lookup): the higher the number, the shorter the average wavelength.. faster alternations
- `uptime`: the average fraction of the time the wave is at `amplitude` (expressed 0-1)
- `amplitude`: the 'up' value of the wave.

in a driver expression, called something like this:

`pulse(frame, 0.2, 0.2, 2)`

To get it to work in 2.79:

- Create a new text-block in a text editor window, give it a name ('Xxx.py')
- Copy and paste the script into the text window, and in its header, click 'Run Script'
- With the target object selected, right-click the attribute of the object you want to be driven.(Let's say Location > Z in the transform panel)
- Select 'Add Drivers' > 'Manually Create Later (single)'
- Open a Graph Editor window, set it from 'f-Curves' to 'Drivers'. You should see the drivers for the selected object listed on the left, if you open that region.
- Hit 'N' if necessary, and reveal the properties region on the right, hit the 'Divers' tab.
- Select 'Scripted Expression' and copy the expression given above into the 'Expr' field.

If everything has gone well, in a range of 250 frames, you should see your object jump intermittently.

You will want to make changes.. come back with them.

you could modify the function, or elaborate the expression to control, say, the `amplitude` parameter, to get behaviours based on the wave.

By going to the header 'Object' menu in the 3D view  > Animation > Bake Action > 'Visual Keying', you can bake the driver's results to key frames, and delete the driver.

Comment: When it comes to the Blender API I am a bloody newbie...in which way I need to "insert" this and where to see the effects of this script?

Comment: This is not keyframes, it's a Driver expression  so it's 'live'.. not baked into an fcurve .. (which may or may not be appropriate for you).. sorry, I only offered up keyframes by contrast.. a guide to how to get this version to work via the UI will depend on the version you're in .. 2.79 or 2.8?

Comment: Currently I am using 2.79. So...any help is welcome :)

Comment: @mcc See edit..